# Переадресация в htaccess на страницу 404

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, dle

Здравствуйте! Сделала переадресацию на сайт в htaccess таким образом:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

И в корне создала файл 404.html

Проблема в том, что все работает, если в конце страницы есть расширение, т.е. если она имеет вид http://example.ru/selfi/830-self.jpg, http://example.ru/selfi/830-self.html и т.д, но если расширения в конце нет, т.е. страница вида http://example.ru/selfi/830-self - то редирект на 404 не срабатывает и показывается пустая страница. Как можно дополнить код, чтобы редирект срабатывал и в случае несуществующей страницы, в конце которой нет расширения? Если имеет значение, то сайт на dle. Спасибо заранее!

Вот весь файл htaccess (все, что ниже оформлено прежним владельцем сайта, я трогать не стала):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html



php_value post_max_size 58M
php_value upload_max_filesize 58M



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.games-forbaby.ru$
RewriteRule (.*) http://games-forbaby.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://games-forbaby.ru/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://games-forbaby.ru/ [R=301,L]



# ���������
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?cstart=$1 [L]

# ��� ����
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&cstart=$5&news_name=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/print:page,([0-9]+),(.*).html(/?)+$ engine/print.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_name=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?newsid=$4&news_page=$2&cstart=$3&seourl=$5&seocat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$2&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html(/?)+$ engine/print.php?news_page=$2&newsid=$3&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([0-9]+)-(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?newsid=$2&seourl=$3&seocat=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$1&cstart=$2&seourl=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?newsid=$2&news_page=$1&seourl=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html(/?)+$ engine/print.php?news_page=$1&newsid=$2&seourl=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*).html(/?)+$ index.php?newsid=$1&seourl=$2 [L]

# �� ����
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&cstart=$4 [L]
# �� ���� �����
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&cstart=$3 [L]
# ����� �� ���� ���
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
# ����� ���������� ����
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?do=tags&tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=tags&tag=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
# ����� �� ��� �����
RewriteRule ^xfsearch/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?do=xfsearch&xf=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^xfsearch/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=xfsearch&xf=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
# ����� ��� ���������� �����
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/rss.xml$ engine/rss.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=userinfo&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=userinfo&user=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/news(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/news/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/news/rss.xml(/?)+$ engine/rss.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1 [L]
# ����� ���� ��������� ��������
RewriteRule ^lastnews/(/?)+$ index.php?do=lastnews [L]
RewriteRule ^lastnews/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=lastnews&cstart=$1 [L]
# ����� � ���� ��������
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)/rss.xml$ engine/rss.php?catalog=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?catalog=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?catalog=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
# ����� ������������� ������
RewriteRule ^newposts(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=newposts [L]
RewriteRule ^newposts/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=newposts&cstart=$1 [L]
# ����� ��������� ������
RewriteRule ^favorites(/?)+$ index.php?do=favorites [L]
RewriteRule ^favorites/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=favorites&cstart=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^rules.html$ index.php?do=rules [L]
RewriteRule ^statistics.html$ index.php?do=stats [L]
RewriteRule ^addnews.html$ index.php?do=addnews [L]
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ engine/rss.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ uploads/sitemap.xml [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=cat&category=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/rss.xml$ engine/rss.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page,([0-9]+),([^/]+).html$ index.php?do=static&page=$2&news_page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^print:([^/]+).html$ engine/print.php?do=static&page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$ index.php?do=static&page=$1 [L]
AddDefaultCharset cp1251
```

Comment: Весть .htaccess показывайте, а то может у вас там еще куча правил.

Comment: Внесла правки в вопрос, добавила файл htaccess

Comment: У вас все запросы с несуществующих файлов идут в index.php. Вам следует разобраться в его коде и вместо отдачи пустой страницы отдавать заголовок `header('404 Not Found');` и содержимое файла `/404.html` -> `readfile('404.html');
    exit;`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это, видимо, стандартный htaccess для dle сайта. Но не могли бы вы посоветовать какой-либо код для перенаправления с несуществующих страниц без расширения в конце на страницу 404? В остальных случаях ведь все работает...

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за ваш совет, попробую разобраться.